# Origin of hierarchical structuring

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, air

Why are libraries located behind `com/` or `net/` directory structures?

Comment: Good question; I've always wondered this as well +1

Comment: Why do all the answers have a down vote each?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is agnostic to Flash, Flex or any language.  It's been used for a long time in general software development.  I believe it stemmed from the [Java package structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_package), but I'm not sure.  It's used because it's now a standard on how to do things and helps split up projects in a fairly unique way.

It normally goes like `<domain extension>/<domain>/<project name>/<sub component>/<whatever>`.

Comment: domain names are used as packages since most software producing entities already own a domain name. It allows them to creat a safe namespace for of their classes. 
Imagine if this were not the case: How many people would write a class called "VideoPlayer" or "Button" or "SoundManager". By allowing you to use your domain name as a package name you get the freedom to work with whatever naming convention you choose without fear of class name collisions with other libraries.

Answer (score 3):

This format/structure is called the **reverse domain name** structure. This structure is used for the package namespace for your classes.

Here is a good article on [The Classpath Demystified by Jody Hall](http://theflashconnection.com/content/classpath-demystified)

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about class packages the point is every package should be unique. Imagine you wrote a class named `MyGreatClass`. Without any package or within some simple package `test.MyGreatClass` (this is called fully qualified class name). In this project you've decided to use some library where somebody wrote another `test.MyGreatClass` class (he/she didn't realize you have another one). So you'll have a conflict of two classes.

To avoid that situation there is a convention to start classes with author's site name in reverse order. Taking in mind every domain name is unique. Following this convention you can be sure you class won't conflict with others.

As far as `com` and `net` are most common domains you can see `com.example` (for http://example.com/) and `net.example` (for http://example.net/) very often.

Answer (score 0):

Advantages of OOP
Inheritance 
maintainability
Re-usability

A class is considered an object.
Having a package structure allows for all the advantages of OOP
Having a standard folder "com" where all your custom classes are allows you to reuse those classes with ease.

All libraries that I did not create, I make sure goes into my com folder. So when I make a new project I just have to point the project settings to that folder, then I can access those libraries with just having to do an import statement.

For example The AS3crypto library I have in the com folder.